# OpenGL GLFW GLAD shared between projects Visual C++

Tags: c++, opengl, dll, glfw

Under Visual C++ 2017, I have a on a side a project DLL, with the core GLFW 3.2.1 routines (like `glfwInit()`, `glfwWindowShouldClose()`, `glfwTerminate()`...). Theses methods are encapsulated in a static class named RenderLoop. It uses GLAD and GLM too.
On the other side I have an EXE project application which calls the RenderLoop methods, in the same solution.

Everything works fine, I launch the exe, the window is created, the loop is running etc...
Yet I try to call within my EXE some gl function (like `glGenVertexArrays`), after Initialization. I can't get rid of Access Violation Exception.

If I put this gl function in the DLL, everything works fine. If I put it in the EXE, it crashes. Is there a "trick" to share OpenGL between the DLL and EXE ?

Comment: Not sure by did you try initialising GLAD in your EXE process?  I don't think loading the DLL will magically give you all the function pointers GLAD sets in the dll.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I added a call to gladLoadGLLoader and it did the trick
Many Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested Robinson, I added a call to gladLoadGLLoader in the dll after Initialization